# Question in the body! (recognizing link with a path + removing http, https and the path)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Me, and a friend of mine has worked on an anti-phishing bot, although Discord themself are detecting the links now.

We've successfully made the bot detect and take action if a link is detected with the API we use, so for example, I'll use example.com, but the real link is a scam link.

The current code below:

```js
const regex = /^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6})(?:\/[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&//=]+)?$/

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.content.match(regex)) {
    let msg = message.content;
    let result = msg.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, "");
    let newresult = msg.replace(/^(?:\w+:)?\/\/[^\/]+/, "");
    fetch(`https://apiurl/check/${result} || https://apiurl/check/${newresult}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      if (json == true) {
        message.delete();
      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor("#ed553e")
      .setAuthor({ name: "Phishing Link Detected", iconURL: message.author.avatarURL() })
      .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
      .setDescription("**User: **" + "<@" + message.author.id + ">" + "\n" + "**ID: **" + "`" + message.author.id + "`" + "\n" + "**Domain: **" + "||" + result + "||")
      .setTimestamp()
      message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
    });
  }
});
```

I've been playing around with the regex, but the bot seems to not detect any link now, so, my question is: **How can I make the bot detect if a link with a path has been send** And also, **How can I make the bot remove the http + https and the path before sending the embed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your `regex` variable. To get the domain, you should use the `URL` class. It's pretty useful to do all the parsing job for you.

```js
const regex = /^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6})(?:\/[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&\/\/=]+)?$/

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.content.match(regex)) {
    let msg = message.content;
    let url = new URL(message.content);
    fetch(`https://apiurl/check/${result} || https://apiurl/check/${newresult}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      if (json == true) {
        message.delete();
      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor("#ed553e")
      .setAuthor({ name: "Phishing Link Detected", iconURL: message.author.avatarURL() })
      .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
      .setDescription("**User: **" + "<@" + message.author.id + ">" + "\n" + "**ID: **" + "`" + message.author.id + "`" + "\n" + "**Domain: **" + "||" + url.host + "||")
      .setTimestamp()
      message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
    });
  }
});
```